# Working time of webhook in dialogflow or alternative

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm writing a bot for myself, which could, on request, find torrents and download them to my home media center.

I receive an error with my webhook: request lives only ~ 5 seconds.

Parsers work 1-10 seconds + home server on hackberry is very slow.

With this, my requests die at 50%.

How can I query and receive an answer after more then 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action is expected to respond within 5 seconds. This does not necessarily have to be the exact answer, but you'll need to have something to let the user know that your action is still processing.

This could be as simple as giving an intermediary state like, "Okay, I'm going to start. Do you want anything else?", or playing a short MediaResponse as "hold music". Then you can store the state in a short-term and quick to access database which is easy to poll and give as a status update when the user asks.

Comment: Okey, suppose, user request "search film %filname%". Server start parsing and send replonse to user with text "loading...". How i can send response to user after loading was finished if dialogflow don't wait for second response?

Comment: In [the docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses), it states that you'll receive another intent once the media response ends.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done through followUpEvents. You can call any intent through web hook's followUpEvent. So, to solve your problem, you have to maintain states in your web application like "searching", "found", "downloading" and "downloaded", it's completely upto you.

Now, once an initial intent is called, you initiate the process on your server then hold for 3-3.5 seconds and send a followUpEvent to call other intent which will do nothing but wait another 3-3.5 seconds and keep polling your server each second for updated status. You can keep calling next follow up intents till you get your desired status from server.

So if your request die at 50% on a single intent then it should work fine with two follow up intents.